# Submit array of tag names and convert to entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to do such a trick: submit tag names as an array and then convert them to entities. Submitted data:

```
{"title":"Title","description":"Desc", "tags": ["first", "second"]}
```

Form:

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('imageFile')
            ->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ImageTagType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Image::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_image';
    }


}
```

Form for image tag:

```
class ImageTagType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ImageTag'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_imagetag';
    }


}
```

The entities are connected with many-to-many. One image can have many tags and one tag can have many images. I am building an API and want to simplify tags submission. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html). Example:

```
....

$builder->get('YOUR_FILED')
    ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($array) {
            // your implementation here
        },
        function ($array) {
            if (!$array) {
                return;
            }

            return new ArrayCollection(array_map(function ($data) {
                return $this->someRepository->findOneBy(['FIELD' => $data]);
            }, $array));
        }
    ));

....
```